# Words begin or end with X, Y, or Z to describe price/quality of services/products

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice

I'm looking for a set of words which begin or end with letter "x", "y", or "z" to describe differentiated price levels or quality of services/products.

> Purpose of this question:

To label services/products into 3 categories by their price or quality.

For example:

- Word with "x" should mean "cheap, least expensive, but less quality"
- Word with "y" should mean "best value, balanced with price and quality"
- Word with "z" should mean "premium, most expensive, but highest quality"

> Rules:

- The words don't need to be correct grammatically.
- The words read (sound) exactly the same as original word.
- The words can be slangs / new words.
- The words don't need to be found from "Oxford dictionary".

> Words I came up with:

`luX` (from luxury)

`cheapy` `pricy`

I couldn't come up with any words with "z". And I'd like your suggestions for "x" and "y" as well.

Comment: So it can mean any price level? It might help if you added more explanation of why you need words like these. There are a lot of free online tools you can use to search for words that start or end in particular letters, like http://www.wordfind.com/ends-with/z/

Comment: @sumelic Thanks for your link. I've edited the original question above. Hope that clarifies.

Comment: the reduX, the mezzY, and the shiZ.  (the reduced, the mezzo, and the sh*t)

Answer (score 1):

There are few options for x, many for y and, for z, it's a challenge. I would then propose:

- x : e**x**pedient (fit or suitable for the purpose; proper under the circumstances)
- y : worth**y** (having adequate or great merit, character, or value; recommandable)
- z : pri**z**ed (highly valued or esteemed; exceptionally desirable)

*I think that you should add another rule, i.e. a word shall only contain one of the 3 letters*.